# RegEx for capturing children attribute values of the first parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, xml, regex-group

I'm parsing a XML file with nodejs and RegExp, but i don't find the way to extract all children from a parent, for example i need all FormalName="(.+)" from parent PARENT1

```
<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
    </Topic>
</TopicSet>
<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT2">
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
    </Topic>
</TopicSet>
```

I tried this :

`<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">(?:(?:\s|\S)*?)TopicType FormalName="(.+)"(?:(?:\s|\S)*?)<\/TopicSet>`

But it only returns the first occurence (Child1) of PARENT1, and not Child1, Child2 and Child3

https://regex101.com/r/3ESH29/2/

Answer (score 3):

It is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to parse xml with a regex.

Instead of using a regex, you might use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and for example use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the values of `FormalName` in PARENT1:

Example using [jsdom](https://repl.it/repls/FlawedRoundOpengroup)

```js
let xml = `<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
    </Topic>
</TopicSet>
<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT2">
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
    </Topic>
    <Topic>
      <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
    </Topic>
</TopicSet>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
let res = doc.querySelectorAll("TopicSet[FormalName='PARENT1'] Topic TopicType");
res.forEach(e => console.log(e.getAttribute("FormalName")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best idea to do that with regular expressions. However, if you have to, you might want to create three capturing groups with parent open/close tags as left/right boundaries and swipe everything in between:

```
(<TopicSet.*?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/TopicSet>)
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vmZOOl/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(<TopicSet.*?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/TopicSet>)/mg;
const str = `<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
 </Topic>
</TopicSet>
<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT2">
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
 </Topic>
</TopicSet>`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### JavaScript Demo 2

If you wish to also print the parent tag, you can simply replace it with `$1$2$3` instead of `$2`, which here we have added to be just simple to call:

```js
const regex = /(<TopicSet.*?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/TopicSet>)/mg;
const str = `<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
 </Topic>
</TopicSet>
<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT2">
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child1" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child2" />
 </Topic>
 <Topic>
   <TopicType FormalName="Child3" />
 </Topic>
</TopicSet>`;
const subst = `$1$2$3`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SgMlEQ/1/)

---

If you only want to extract the first parent, you can add another boundary:

```
(<TopicSet FormalName="PARENT1">)([\s\S]*?)(<\/TopicSet>)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rjr0pg/1)